# Firefox IndexedDB

Tags: firefox, indexeddb

1) Set up
Windows 7 Ultimate, Database PostgreSQL, Apache Webserver
For testing, the database, web server and the app is run on the same machine.

Mozilla Firefox ver 62.0.X

### Google Chrome ver 69.x.x

2) I run the following code to populate IndexedDB data-store.
The function is called from within XMLHttpRequest synchronous call to PHP.
Each page retrieves data from PostgreSQL from a table unique to it, as required. For testing, anything from 10 to 150 records from PostgreSQL are retrieved. When the web age is closed, the IndexedDB database is deleted, so every page load is a fresh start from scratch.

```
    function jIDBUpload(vdbdata,vlib)
    {
      vIDBrequest = window.indexedDB.open('MyIDB');
      vIDBrequest.onupgradeneeded = function() {
      vIDBdbase = vIDBrequest.result;
      vIDBobjstore = vIDBdbase.createObjectStore(vlib, { keyPath: "id"});
      vIDBobjstore.createIndex('vInx','id',{unique: true});
      vlength =vdbdata.length;
      for(l=0;l<=vlength-1;l++) 
     {
        vIDBobjstore.put(vdbdata[l]);   
     }
   }; 
  }
```

I have also tried using the second & third line of code as (but no luck).

```
  vIDBrequest.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
  vIDBdbase = e.target.result;
```

3) The issue

In chrome, the above code runs succesffuly 100% of the time. No issues at all.

In Firefox, it is a case of hit & miss, sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. This behaviour is random.
Reloading the page also does not guarantee success.

4) Any insights, suggestions and/or solutions?

Comment: Explicitly provide the version parameter when calling indexedDB.open, and use the success event handler to insert data instead of doing so within onupgradeneeded. My instinct suggests this is related to differences in the upgradeneeded event firing. My suggested changes will make the difference more pronounced.

Comment: Thanks, Josh. Will do the needful & test. Will get back with the results.

Comment: @josh Solved. The problem was not of version parameter, per se. An indexeddb database (with varying data-stores) is opened with every page and deleted when the page is closed. The delete utility - deleteDatabase was not getting fired regularly, hence the next time the page was loaded, Firefox would not open the database (was not an issue with Chrome) . I solved the problem, by running the deleteDatabase command at the start when the page is loaded.